# The system can not find the path Specified while running a remotely located batch file

Tags: java, batch-file, cmd, sas

I am getting an error--: "The system can not find the path Specified", while running a remotely located batch file.Please help me out.

Thanks IN ADVANCE.

**sas.bat:**

```
"D:\sas home\SASFoundation\9.3\sas.exe" -SYSIN c:\codeexcel.sas
cmd /k
```

**Java Code:**

```
public static void main(String arr[])
{
    String cmd="cmd /c start \\\\xx.xx.xx.xx\\batch\\sas.bat";
    try 
    {
        Process r = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
    } catch (Exception e) 
    {
        System.out.println("Execution error");
    } 
}
```

**Error Message:**

```
D:\sas home\SASFoundation\9.3\sas.exe" -SYSIN c:\codeexcel.sas
The system can not find the path Specified
```

Comment: Is it sas.bat or sas.exe?

Comment: Its seems like mismatch in the path that is specified in java code and the actual path seems different.

Comment: It is SAS.bat file not a SAS.exe.

Comment: There is a space inside your Path `D:\sas home\SASFoundation\9.3\sas.exe" -SYSIN c:\codeexcel.sas`. Try to set it this way `"D:\sas home\SASFoundation\9.3\sas.exe" -SYSIN c:\codeexcel.sas`also maybe add a 'start', like this `start "D:\sas home\SASFoundation\9.3\sas.exe" -SYSIN c:\codeexcel.sas`

Comment: is the bat file executes fine through the command line? If it does then try changing the path/location specified in the java code. i.e. \\\\xx.xx.xx.xx\\batch\\sas.bat this

Comment: Dear Bilbo Baggins can U plz suggest me a path that what I have to put in my java code?

Comment: Pankaj I would try suggestion from @ScreamingTree

Comment: In addition make sure that your `.bat` is working correct in the cmd before you trie to execute it inside java like @Bilbo Baggins suggested

Comment: Dear Bilbo Baggins  Now I am getting An new error that --: The system cannot find a file -SYSIN

Comment: Dear Bilbo Baggins .bat is working correct in the cmd before I trie to execute it inside java.

plz help me out Thanks In advance

Comment: Is anyone is there to help me out??